# Ruby generate XML documents with period in attribute

Tags: ruby, xml, jenkins, nokogiri

There are lots of great Ruby libraries out there to generate XML documents, but I can't find any which support the generation of XML attributes with periods in their names.

The end goal here is to build a Ruby lib which auto generates Jenkins templates.

Here is an example Jenkins job field parameter, which as you can see, uses attributes with periods in the name:

```
<properties>
  <hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty>
    <parameterDefinitions>
      <hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
        <name>MESSAGE</name>
        <description/>
        <defaultValue>Hello world!</defaultValue>
      </hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
    </parameterDefinitions>
  </hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty>
</properties>
```

Does anyone know how I could do this? Any way to bend the libraries which already exist to support this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Note, as asked your question wasn't a good fit for SO. You're supposed to show us the minimum code that demonstrated the problem, along with errors encountered, the required supporting input data and expected output. That shows us what you tried and helps us not duplicate things you tried. "[ask]" and the links at the bottom of that page, and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" help explain the process and what we need.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use dynamic dispatching:

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.properties {
    xml.send('foo.bar', 'zaa')
  }
end
```

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<properties>
  <foo.bar>zaa</foo.bar>
</properties>
```

Comment: BTW, in this case, it does not matter much, but you should as a general rule prefer `public_send` over `send`. `send` does two things, allow you to pass a method name dynamically, and circumvent access protection. Since your method name in this case is not actually dynamic, someone reading the code may assume that you are using `send` for its other effect then. Whereas with `public_send`, it would be immediately obvious that you only use it because the method name is illegal. Only use `send` when you actually *mean* to break encapsulation.

Comment: Congratulations on finding your own solution. SO will let you select your answer as the solution after a time-out period. You might want to test and incorporate @JörgWMittag's suggestion, crediting him appropriately, and add that to your answer to make it more complete. Don't add "updated" or "edited" tags to the text, just add the new information where you would have if you'd originally entered it.